# How to use "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, this, classname

im fairly newb when it comes to writing pure javascript, but i want to learn and become better.
i have a code below, what im trying to do in the if block doesnt matter so much, but what is tripping me up is using "this". below i want wrap to have classname if condition is true, but its not working.
Can anyone please explain why is "this" not working in my code below?

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap")

if(wrap.innerHTML.length === 0){
    this.className="empty"
}
```

Comment: Uh, why did you expect it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `wrap.className = "empty"`.

`this` refers to the current "execution context" (which you can get a great explanation of in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)). The fact that you're within an `if` statement doesn't change the execution context or anything... if you're just trying to add that className to the `wrap` element like you suggest, then apply the className to `wrap` not `this`.